# How to automatically tag file by name or extension

Tags: macos, terminal, macbook-pro

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically tag a file as it reaches your computer, like downloads, copying from an external drive, etc. I would like to simulate gmail filters, like labelling every email as it reaches your mail.

I would prefer if we could do this by name, but if it could be done by extension, that would be ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple offer [Folder Actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_folder_actions.html) to attach AppleScripts to folders. You can attach an AppleScript to perform any task with incoming files to a specific folder.

See [Folder Actions Tutorial: Automation, Meet the Filesystem](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/folder-actions-tutorial-automation-meet-the-filesystem/) for a tutorial and step-by-step guide.

[image]